# Bold item after selection Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Now I am using Navigation Drawer with Fragments and selected items highlighted red color.
I wand to use bold typeface for choosen item instead of highlighting. Can anyone say me, how can i realise this?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0]));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1]));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2]));

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer_white, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        displayView(0);
    }
}


private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        displayView(position);
    }
}

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new MainFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new TheoryFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();


        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

**DrawerAdapter**

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return navDrawerItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {       
    return navDrawerItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

UPD:
I understand how to bold checked item, it is not removed when switching to a different item  and does not have a bold style from the start.

**Updated Code**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        View rowView = view;
        TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        displayView(position);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's my complete solution...

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
     setNavDrawerItemNormal();
     TextView txtview = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNav));
     txtview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
}

public void setNavDrawerItemNormal()
{
    for (int i=0; i< mDrawerListView.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = mDrawerListView.getChildAt(i);
        TextView txtview = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNav));
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        txtview.setTypeface(font);
    }
}
```

And to bold the first item in the navigation drawer upon initialization of the app, I did that in the list adapter get view method...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_item, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtNav);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    if (position == 0) { textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD); }

    return rowView;
}
```

So, in here i checked if the position of the item is 0 (meaning its the first item), then make it bold. This whole thing works perfectly for me!~

Comment: I guess your answer is misleading, because it'd be better to use standart Checkable interface for list items and use `myDrawerListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)`.
In your case you definitely have to use CheckedTextView instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your SlideMenuClickListeners onItemClick, set all items to `Typeface.DEFAULT` and then set the item you're interested in to `Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parent.getCount(); i++) {
    TextView v = (TextView)parent.getChildAt(i);
    if (v != null)
        v.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
}
((TextView)view).setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

To get rid of the highlighting upon selection, remove `mDrawerList.setChecked` and `mDrawerList.setSelection` in your `displayView` method

However, take this solution with a grain of salt because I'm having trouble emboldening the first item upon initialization of the app.